# Use MATHEMATICA to calculate the volume of the solid

Tags: numerical-integration

Use MATHEMATICA to calculate the volume of the solid that results when the region enclosed by the given curves is revolved about the x- axis. 
f(x)=Pi^2 Sin[x] Cos[x]^3, f(x)=  4 x^2     x=0, x=Pi/4

Comment: Please post your ideas and tell us where you got stuck. Otherwise you're just asking for somebody to do your homework (And your TA could be around!)

Comment: i have used 3D...   ContourPlot[Pi^2 Sin[x] Cos[x]^3, 4 x^2, {x, 0, Pi/4}, Axes -> True, 
 Frame -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]

Comment: i want the gra[ph in 2D

Answer (score 5):

This volume between the regions can be obtained as follows:

```
f[x_] := Pi^2 Sin[x] Cos[x]^3
g[x_] := 4 x^2
v1 = Integrate[Pi g[z]^2, {z, 0, Pi/4}]
v2 = Integrate[Pi f[z]^2, {z, 0, Pi/4}]
N[v2 - v1]
```

yielding: [Pi]^6/320,(1/48 + (5 [Pi])/512) [Pi]^5, 12.7596 respectively.

You can use a number of v10 capabilities to  visualize region and approximate volume (the second integral in straightforward but the first is problematic for `Volume`/`RegionMeasure` unless region is discretized).

```
ir1 = ImplicitRegion[y^2 + z^2 <= g[x]^2 && 0 < x < Pi/4, {x, y, z}];
ir2 = ImplicitRegion[y^2 + z^2 <= f[x]^2 && 0 < x < Pi/4, {x, y, z}];
roi = RegionDifference[ir2, ir1];
Volume[DiscretizeRegion[roi]]
```

yields: 12.0382

Visualizing region (with no particular emphasis on quality, just for illustration)

```
DiscretizeRegion@roi
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `Region` approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
ftop = Pi^2  Sin[x] Cos[x]^3
fbtm = 4 x^2;
Plot[{ftop, fbtm}, {x, 0, Pi/4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `Volume = Pi  r^2 * h` (cylinder volume) for top and bottom and take the difference (i.e remove volume of inner cylinder from outer)

```
vtop = Pi Integrate[ftop^2, {x, 0, Pi/4}];
vbtm = Pi Integrate[fbtm^2, {x, 0, Pi/4}];
vtop - vbtm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N[%]
 (* 12.7596 *)
```

The area of the cross section, if you want it, is

```
 Integrate[ftop - fbtm, {x, 0, Pi/4}] // N
 (*1.20459*)
```